# How to write data from a dict via Django ORM in SQLite?

Tags: python-3.x, django, sqlite, django-models

How the models should look like in Django 1.11 so that I can write this data in them? And how to write this data?

```
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
    "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
  }
]

[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Leanne Graham",
    "username": "Bret",
    "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
    "address": {
      "street": "Kulas Light",
      "suite": "Apt. 556",
      "city": "Gwenborough",
      "zipcode": "92998-3874",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-37.3159",
        "lng": "81.1496"
      }
]
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should create

- A user model with `first_name`, `last_name`, `username`, `email`
- An address model with those fields and a foreign key to user
- And another model with a ForeignKey to user with `title` and `body`

here is an example from the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/)

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

Django has a built-in user model if you prefer.